# Using autoNumeric 4.x with Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am currently using [autoNumeric 1.9.46](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/tree/1.9.x) in one of my ember projects. I installed it as a bower dependency; since it is a jQuery plugin and added

```
app.import(`bower_components/autoNumeric/autoNumeric.js`);
```

to `ember-cli-build.js` file and it is all good. I can use it as described in documentation as `$(selector).autoNumeric()`.

Now I decided to use [autoNumeric v4.0.0-beta.14](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/tree/v4.0.0-beta.14); but it seems to be ES6 module now. I tried to install it through `npm install autonumeric` and import it via `import AutoNumeric from "AutoNumeric"` but I got "Could not find module `AutoNumeric` imported from ..." error. I tried to install it through `ember-browserify` as described in [here](http://www.jimmylauzau.com/blog/2016/03/22/importing-node-modules-in-ember-js) and import it as `import AutoNumeric from 'npm:AutoNumeric'` and still the same error. Can somebody help me in using autoNumeric v4.0.0-beta.14, which is now an ES6 module? I am open to any help in directing using custom ES6 modules with Emberjs as well. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @alptugd, have you tried specifying the whole `node_modules/autonumeric/dist/autoNumeric.min.js` path in your import?

Comment: @alptugd Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @splattne unfortunately not. it is still in my to-do list. I will post an answer to this question if I ever find a solution.